Frontend Enqueued Files in the Backend
I am currently developing a plugin and I need to get the handlers of various enqueued files in the theme. I have tried working with global $wp_scripts and global $wp_styles, but I only get the scripts and styles that are loaded for the backend (which is expected).
However, it is crucial for me to know the handlers in the backend so that I can dequeue them from there.
Can anyone help?
Best regards
Edit:
Here is an example of what I am trying to implement:
it should not only work with static paths but with different file types and files.
function json_file_handler() {

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Path to the staging JS file in the theme directory

        $json_file_path = get_template_directory() . '/assets/js/staging_core.js';

        // Check if the file exists
        if (file_exists($json_file_path)) {
            // If the file exists, dequeue the default script and enqueue the staging script
            wp_dequeue_script('core');
            wp_deregister_script('core');
            wp_enqueue_script('staging-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/staging_core.js', array('jquery'), _S_VERSION, true);
        }
    }
}

sorry I don't know why it only shows one part as code

You can't be sure what will be enqueued on the frontend without making a frontend request, but even then it can change depending on the type of page, who makes the request, and the blocks present on the page. Finding registered rather than enqueued scripts/styles might be easier but it all depends on what you're trying to do that requires this, the context will be super helpful here. As for dequeuing, that happens on the request, the only way to dequeue a frontend script is to run code on the frontend request that enqueued it. Remember each request loads WP from a blank slate.

i have edited my question and hope it helps to understand my problem i am still a beginner in plugin programming and apologize if i am unclear :)
